# Linking an SMS reply to the original message

Tags: twilio, sms

We want to be able to send an SMS using Twilio and the person receiving should be able to reply to the message thread.

How can I link the reply to the original message? (In e-mail we just put the thread->id in the reply address)

The person receiving could be in multiple threads.

Twilio seems to suggest cookies but I don't see how this could work.

Mick

Comment: SMS does not provide threads. A reply is not actually a replay. If you take the time of the message and the topic of the message out of the context, you would not know if it's a replay or just a new message. The only way I see to do threading in SMS is to use a different phone number when you send or use some id in each message.

Comment: @Mick what does 'the person receiving could be in multiple threads' mean ?

Comment: The receiving mobile could be in multiple conversations (threads) with the sending mobile. I need to identify which conversation to add the message to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's nothing in SMS that allows for a message to be replied to directly. If you check your own phone and its SMS application you will find that you can't reply, just send another message in chronological order.

One option you have is to buy and use multiple numbers to communicate with your users. You only need as many numbers as you have open threads with a user, but that is a way to segregate messages between your application and an end user.